# How to count number number of users with whom the file is shared in Django?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have two models like this:

```
class File(models.Model):
    users = models.ForeignKey(User)
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start_date = models.TextField()
    end_date = models.TextField()
    duration = models.TextField()
    size_overview = models.IntegerField()
    size = models.TextField()
    flag = models.TextField()
    #delete_date = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

class Share(models.Model):
    users = models.ForeignKey(User)
    files = models.ForeignKey(File)
    shared_user_id = models.IntegerField()
    shared_date = models.TextField()
```

I want to count the person with whom the file is shared. For example if the file ok.txt is shared with 2 people I want to show the file_information and show the value of shared_with coloumn 2. 
I do like this:

```
    file_s = Share.objects.filter(users_id=log_id)
 shared_with = Share.objects.filter(files_id__in = file_s).values_list('shared_user_id', flat=True).distinct().count()
```

But it's showing the same shared_with number for each file. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** Actually my query is correct but I didn't know how to call this in template:

```
#views.py
def shared_by_me(request):
    try: 
        log_id = request.user.id
        username = request.user.username

        #Shared by me file information
        file_s = Share.objects.filter(users_id=log_id)

        b = [i.files_id for i in file_s]
        c = map(str, b)
        c = ''.join(c)
        shared_with = Share.objects.filter(files_id__in = file_s).values_list('shared_user_id', flat=True).distinct().count() 
        shared_file = File.objects.filter(id__in= Share.objects.filter(users_id = log_id).values_list('files', flat=True))
        #shared_username = User.objects.filter(id__in= Share.objects.filter(users_id = log_id).values_list('shared_user_id', flat=True))
        shared_username = Share.objects.filter(shared_user_id=log_id)
        #shared_file = File.objects.filter(id__in = c, users__id = log_id)
        return render_to_response('shared_by_me.html', {'shared_by_me':shared_file, 'shared_with':shared_with, 'username':username, 'shared_username':shared_username}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    except ValueError:
        return render_to_response('shared_by_me.html', {'username':username}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

#template:
    {% for choice in shared_by_me %}
            <tr class="oddclass">
              <td><input type="checkbox" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" onchange="checkChecked()"/></td>
              <td><label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.file_name }}</label></td>
              <td>{{ choice.type }}</td>
              <td>{{ choice.size }}</td>
              <td>{{ choice.end_date }}</td>
              <td><a href="#" onclick="share()">{{ shared_with }}</a></td>
              {% endfor %}

            </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this?

```
file_s = Share.objects.filter(files__pk = somePk).count()
```

Since every share object corresponds to only one user, this gives that how many `Share` objects have `files` with the primary key `somePk`

and then `count()` just counts the number

Comment: Please see my updated question. My query is correct but I don't know how to call it in template the right way.